# Delete ASCII code at the end of line without deleting the ASCII code in the middle

Tags: java, mysql, expression, ascii, talend

I have a scenario where I store data with ASCII code.

**Example:**

```
"UKI:PPP1ZZ.General to File¦WB"
```

Also I have a scenario where unknowingly some special characters get stored at the end of the line.

**Example:**

```
"UKI:PPP1ZZ.General.File.WELL ".
```

So as it can be seen in my second example, i get ASCII code after 'WELL' which get stored in database as lagging special codes from my Talend ETL job.
Now I wrote an expression in java to be used in Talend to clean the lagging special codes which is below:

```
row1.sheetname.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]","")
```

But the issue which I find with my above expression is that it will replace the ASCII code that is present in my first example which I don't want.
Also the other thing is that I only want to replace the ASCII code that is present at the end of my lines.

So is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: First I'd like you to apply some formatting to make your question more readable.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "I only want to replace the ASCII code that is present at the end of my lines" without replacing anything in your first example. As far as I can see all your example data is ASCII characters so you'd have to be a bit more specific. Do you want to remove whitespace?

Comment: In my second example you could see something similar to whitespace at the end, but that is an ASCII code with values sometime as 202 or 160 as of now which always comes at the end of line. The ASCII codes may change for the end of line, but I want to handle them and remove the ASCII codes at the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
row1.sheetname = row1.sheetname
    .replaceFirst("(?u)([^\u0000-\u001f\u007f]|\\P{ASCII})$","");
```

This removes the last character: ASCII control char or non-ASCII char (capital P is "non-"). `$` = end of text.

Comment: Thanks Joop. When I used the code it removed most of the lagging codes but i still find some lagging and am not able to find out which character it is. Can you please help on that.

Comment: That seems a case of needing a thorough evaluation: exactly checking where it goes wrong. By dumping exact data, splitting the data in pieces to find the error location and such. `.replaceFirst("(?u)([^\u0000-\u001f\u007f]|\\P{ASCII}){1,2}$","");` would try to remove up to 2 control characters, like in CR+LF.

Comment: I tried the new change but this is also truncating my data from some of the rows for example :if i have a record like "UKI:PPP1ZZ.General.File.WELL",    this is getting truncated to UKI:PPP1ZZ.General.File.WE.
But this is working for some rows. So can you please let me know if any other solutions exists.

Comment: Sorry, best would be to dump the data in hex and esplore the concerning records. Because the rest seems guess work.